# Add dict key from list if list value isn't already a dict key

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Is there a way to make the following code more efficient?  Namely, how can I avoid the need to first make the empty dict?

```
lst = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]

dct = {}

dct = {num: lst.count(num) for num in lst if num not in dct}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to initiate an empty dict before, just delete that line and everything will still work.

Comment: You can also use [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), ```from collections import Counter; dict(Counter([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]))```

Comment: The code as posted *does* need that empty dict, because it's doing membership tests on it.  However, those tests are pointless - `num not in dct` will ALWAYS be true, because it's not until the very end of the dict comprehension that anything is actually assigned to `dct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `set()`:

```
lst = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]

dct = {key: lst.count(key) for key in set(lst)}
print(dct)
```

Which yields

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sushanth's solution is the best optimized:

```
import collections

lst = [1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4]

dct = collections.Counter(lst)
print(dct)
```